# Orange Fungi on Oak tree

Tags: mycology

The fungus in my profile pic is bright orange in a ball growing out of the cut off branches scar, also in a necklace.  There are egg shell white broken balls instead of the orange balls-suggesting the orange ball explodes and the seed depart leaving the white shell bottom.

Comment: The picture is missing, please add it for clarity.

Comment: @Chris look at her profile pic :-)

Comment: Too small! Can't see detail! :(

Comment: http://leslieland.com/2009/09/hunting-laetiporus-sulphureus-the-sulfur-shelf-or-chicken-mushroom/  I think this is the answer.  I have great pictures, but don't know how to add them.